# How to draw a decision tree in R

Tags: r, visualization, draw, decision-tree

I want to present (draw) a flow of decisions starting from root continue decision nodes up to 6 layers.
The decision root (R) will splits into 2 decision options X1 and X2, each of these Xs then divided into 3 new branches of Y1, Y2, and Y3, 
then Ys divided into 3 branches Z1, Z2, and Z3, and so on.
Please note that I am not going to classify or doing recursive analysis.
Any help please?

Comment: You might take a look at the `igraph` package.

Comment: What packages did you try? How was the baser R plot functions unable to help you (I know it would be hard)?

Comment: Why not simply "plot(ctree)", where ctree is your decision tree?

Answer (score 2):

You could use **rpart.plot** package in R which is used to plot Classification and Regression Trees. One such example is 
[image]
 This [link](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/06/plotting-classification-and-regression-trees-with-plotrpart.html) would be helpful for examples.